# How to send post request using Spookyjs with body parameter?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

I want to send a post request with JSON body to a particular server using Spookyjs. How I do that please help into this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spooky, then you are using nodeJS. Gather your informations (which I'm guessing you want to do) with spooky / casper, pass them back to nodeJS, parse your data and post it.

Comment: If you wanted a more specific answer, please elaborate your question.